# Intellij IDEA move element left/right (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Left/Right) doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.01

Tags: intellij-idea, gnome, hotkeys, ubuntu-18.04

It seems that (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>) hotkey is used by Ubuntu, so IDEA can't pick it up.

[image: Idea hotkey]

After googling I found out that these hotkeys are assigned to **move-to-workspace-right** and **move-to-workspace-left** 
Ubuntu actions. But when I disabled those (set [], or ['disabled'])
in Ubuntu, IDEA still can't pick this hotkey up.

[image: Disabled hotkeys]

Could anyone help to find out what other actions can be bind to those hotkeys or how can I get a list of all used keybinding in the Ubuntu. 
(I can't find them in the default Ubuntu settings and gnome tweaks)

**Move-to-workspace-right** and **move-to-workspace-left** is shown only in dconf tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

Along with disabling both **move-to-workspace-right** and **switch-to-workspace-right**;
**move-to-workspace-left** and **switch-to-workspace-left** hotkeys,
need to be sure that **Gnome tweak tool** > **Switching to another layout** does not use any of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

For example, when 
switching to another layout hotkey is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, it means that all other hotkeys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Any key</kbd> will be unavailable.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's out of my mind but combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> works for me.

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

IDEA 2018.3.4

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 21.10 and IDEA 2021.3.3 too - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For my case, all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> hotkeys were disabled in the system. From my understanding, this is due to the fact that the keys for switching layouts intercept these combinations.

I solved this problem by resetting the default mapping options. `Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> Reset All...`.

<s>At the moment I do not know how to save the keyboard switch combination, but there is a thread about it:</s>
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088572/894725) looks pretty good enough.

Comment: I tried to reset all key mapping, but mapping for move-to-workspace-right and move-to-workspace-left is not in the default Ubuntu `Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard`. And I don't think, that Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Left/Right is used to switch between layouts according to the Gnome tweaks.

Comment: What if you set `Move-to-workspace-right` and `Move-to-workspace-left` to `[]` using dconf?